# How not to save public libraries in azure artifacts feed?

Tags: angular, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

I have created an azure artifact feed and published an npm library. When I consume this library in another project, I see that there are so many public npm libraries are saved in my feed, I have added npmjs in upstream sources.

Initially, I felt like a good idea but now I have to use this library and multiple projects, and all public npm packages are saved in the feed.

How to not save the public npm packages and still make the library from feed work.

Answer (score 0):

If we want to use azure feed to help us restore the package, then the pipeline will try to find the package in your feed, if there is not package, it will help you to find the package in the upstream sources, then download the package to your feed.

This is by our design. So, if you want to not save the public package to your feed, you can delete/disable the upstream source. This will not save the public package to your private feed.

But this might cause the error 'package not find' when you restore, so you need to add the
public upstream package in your project package config file. This can be the workaround.

Comment: how would you add it then only for restore?
"so you need to add the public upstream package in your project package config file."

Comment: In your npmrc file, you can add the public source package. And use this npmrc file to help you restore the package.